# Android Cocos2d-x App Slow Resume after minimize Solution

Tags: android, performance, cocos2d-x, onresume

I just wondering if there's a solution for apps that resume too slow.
Mine takes up to 10 seconds to resume.

I know that my app has large assets but is there a way to make it resume faster?
or is they a way to add like an hour glass or to just display a text saying loading or something.

How can I display something to tell the player that it is loading/resuming, as soon as  try to resume the app?

I hope somebody can help me.  Thanks.
And Im using cocos2d-x for this app.

Answer (score 0):

These are the functions to be implemented in your Application Delegate class. The first function gets called when application goes background, and second one is called when application resumes.

```
void CCApplication::applicationDidEnterBackground();
void CCApplication::applicationWillEnterForeground();
```

Comment: I know both of those, but what should i do in there? It will resume Cocos2d-x / the application but is there a simpler way to display an image or text from there? and remove it once the main app resumes/has completed resumes? I just want to solve the problem with the blank screen and waiting time when you try to maximize the app on your android device.